# Non-exhaustive patterns in function take6 error?

Tags: list, haskell, take

So i created this function , to give me the "n" first elements from a list,"(b:bs);

```
 1  module Sexta where  
 2
 3  take6::Int->[a]->[a]
 4  take6 n (b:bs) = if n<=0 then [] 
 5                 else [b] ++ (take6 (n-1) bs)
```

The problem is that when i try: `take6 2 []`, it shows:

```
*** Exception: sexta.hs:(4,1)-(6,15): Non-exhaustive patterns in function take6
```

I dont why, cuz when i try this by hand :

```
   take6 2 []
   = [] ++take6 1 []
   = [] ++[]++take6 0 []
   = [] ++[]++[]
   = []
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your program you write:

```
take6 n (b:bs) = ...
```

But here you thus use a pattern `(b:bs)` which is the "cons" constructor of the list. The cons constructor takes a head `b` and a tail `bs`. The list type has however two constructors: the "cons" we already discussed here, and the empty list `[]`. Haskell is complaining that it can not find a clause for the empty list pattern of the second argument. So your function needs to be defined with a shape:

```
take6 n [] = ...
take6 n (b:bs) = ...
```

Now the question is still what to do here. Regardless of what we take in case of an empty list, we can not emit any elements anymore, so you probably want to return the empty list, so:

```
take6 _ [] = []
```

furthermore you make indeed a distinction between `n` being less than or equal to zero in which case the result is an empty list:

```
take6 n (b:bs) | n <= 0 = []
```

but there is also a case where `n > 0`. In that case we want indeed prepend `b` to the `take6 (n-1) bs`. Mind however that a more efficient way to prepend, is again using the "cons" constructor:

```
               | otherwise = b : take6 (n-1) bs
```

or in full:

```
take6 :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
take6 _ [] = []
take6 n (b:bs) | n <= 0 = []
               | otherwise = b : take6 (n-1) bs
```

Comment: Yes, its potentially more efficient. But when GHC is run with optimizations enabled, they should end up being the same. I haven't checked this example, but there are special rules for desugaring literal lists into `build` forms that should fuse with the `foldr` form in `(++)`. In this case, there's no point relying on this optimization, but I suspect it matters more when using `[a]` as the monoid target of a `foldMap`.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern `b:bs` does not match the empty list. You need a separate case to handle the empty list.

Answer (score 2):

You're destructuring the list before you check *n*, so even if it's 0 you're requiring the list be non-empty.  You could use a guard to handle that case, but that wouldn't help in this case where the list is too short.